# Default parameter in python with objects

Tags: python, pexpect, default-arguments

I know I can define default parameters in python, but can I do so with objects?

For example, I'd like to work with a p.expect object:

```
def exitDevice(ip, m='', sendExit=True):
    if sendExit:
        m.send('exit')

    print "left device", ip
```

Is that the correct way to handle an object passed in as a default argument in Python?  If not, how does one do so?  Or if this is correct is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, since the default value has to be defined at the time your code is parsed, but you can always do something like this:

```
def exitDevice(ip,m=None,sendExit=True):
   if m is None: m = getDefaultValueForM()
   if sendExit: m.send ( 'exit' )
```